# Laravel - Override Jetstream required password length

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

How do I override required password length in Laravel with Jetstream?

In another project all I had to do was go to `Password` class from `vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Rules\Password.php` and set `length` variable to whatever I wanted.

Like so:

```
class Password implements Rule
{
     /**
     * The minimum length of the password.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $length = 3;

    {...}
}
```

In my current project, after trying to install Bootstrap I had to run the command `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`. That messed up the appearance of the register, login and profile views.

So I reinstalled Jetstream and livewire again by running the following commands:

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
```

Now I get an error when I try to create a new user with a password with less than 8 characters, even though my `length` variable in the `Password` class is set to 3:

[image]

I want to set the minimum password length to 3 again. How do I do that?

Thank you in advance.

---

Edit:

I've tried changing the `passwordRules` method from the `PasswordValidationRules` trait to the following:

```
protected function passwordRules()
    {
        return ['required', 'string', (new Password)->length(3), 'confirmed'];
    }
```

But it still didn't work.

Comment: https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#password-validation-rules

Comment: I've tried changing the `passwordRules` method to return `(new Password)->length(3)` instead of `new Password` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in App/Actions/Fortify/PasswordValidationRules.php

change `passwordRules` function to as below (example is for password to be at least 4 in length)

```
protected function passwordRules(): array
{
    $password = new Password();
    $password->length(4);
    return ['required', 'string', $password , 'confirmed'];
}
```

Environment:
Laravel 10.0.2 ; Jetstream 3.1

Answer (score -1):

vendor\laravel\fortify\src\rules\Password.php -> protected $length

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).